# ajax get request to Office365 REST Api fails CORS?

Tags: ajax, cors, office365

I'm attempting to make an ajax GET request to the Office365 RESTful API service from my local server, but am running into cross-domain HTTPRequest errors.  The following is a sample of my 'get-files-at-root' attempt:

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'https://[sharepoint_site]/_api/v1.0/me/files?access_token='+token,
  type: 'get',
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function(data) {
    if (success){
      success(data);
    }
  },
  error: error
})
```

I'm getting the following response from the server:

```
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 403.
```

I've tried sending the access token as a header parameter:

```
headers: {'Authorization': 'Bearer '+ token}
```

but this had the same result.

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

(Background: I'm trying to create my own Office365 'file picker' on the client because I couldn't find an available library for OneDrive Business that supplies this.)

Comment: Are you sure the Sharepoint REST APIs support CORS?

Comment: They do now!  See below...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Office 365 Files API and SharePoint REST have just introduced support for CORS.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/howto/create-web-apps-using-CORS-to-access-files-in-Office-365

What you were trying to do is exactly how it works.  The service will respond to the OPTIONS pre-flight request with an Access-Control-Allow-Origin header.

The authorization in the request must be an Azure Active Directory issued OAuth2 implicit grant access token.

Answer (score 0):

```
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "x-requested-with");
```

Answer (score 0):

You have no idea about CORS. Read the specification: http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/

In your case you have to allow `null` origin, since we are talking about localhost. You have to allow the methods and the headers you send, even the `content-type` header. You have to allow sending credentials, which you can get in the `Authorization` header. You have to handle `OPTIONS` requests with `200 ok`.

Answer (score -3):

Can you try with setting the Access-Control-Allow-Origin in header as shown below.

```
headers: { 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*' }
```

Comment: This header has to be sent as part of the response, not the request.